# Links to local folder on a web page. How to open in file browser?

Tags: linux, firefox, browser

I have the following link on a website file://///path/to/directory
When I click on the link under Linux I want the directory to get opened in a file manager. How to achieve that?

Comment: You mean the web site has a link on a file which is assumed to be on the viewer's PC? This could be forbidden by the browser (possible security issues). And anyway the browser handles the `file://` protocol for itself. At best, if the file has a given extension or a recognized mimetype) you could have the browser open it with the application defined for that on the user's desktop.

Comment: @xenoid yes, the file is on the viewers PC. The website is a tool which is used in my company and it works with firefox under windows. Maybe they made some changes to firefox settings or any policy or so, I don't know. I want use it on a linux machine but atm the only way is to copy and paste the link.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I cant provide a direct step-by-step tutorial to do this, I believe this  SO link will give you everything you need to do this ...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/330937/is-it-possible-to-open-an-ubuntu-app-from-html

Looking through quickly, and I can see no reasons why this answer wouldnt work on all Linux distros. 
Hope it helps